# How to upgrade GLib version in a GTK+ bundle?

Tags: windows, gtk, glib

I'm trying to build a program that requires GTK+ on Windows. However, the make process didn't terminate because apparently the program uses GLib codes that are only available in versions 2.38 and above (and the one that came with the bundle version of GTK+ I have installed is only v2.0).

I have tried to integrate the v2.38 codes in the current program since there is technically only 1 function needed and I didn't want to waste time upgrading GLib, but it failed. I have also tried to replace the whole GLib directory with the newer version (maybe not a good idea), but it made more harm than good.

Maybe just upgrading GLib would be less complicated after all. But I have no idea on how to do that.

What can I do?

Comment: Out of interest: what is the function you need? 2.38 didn't really have much added api so implementing what you need yourself could be the easiest option by far. Btw, I think you may have misread the bundled version number: The 2.0 release is probably a teenager by now...

Comment: g_icon_serialize would be it. I'm not that learned with GNOME and when I looked at the sources, I wasn't very sure if I could patch it up.

Comment: I should've known about that v2.0 thingy. It was smelling fishy all over.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't thinking of Gio. The icon serialization might be a bit tricky to implement yourself: there are  various GIcon implementations that probably include the actual serialization code...

Comment: Care to enlighten me with one such implementation?

P.S. I think this is what I get for trying to build Unix stuff on Windows >_<

Comment: If you look at the GIcon documentation, you'll see that it's an interface and it lists several "Known Implementations". The serialization is done in those implementations: You could write a function that, depending on the type of GIcon, does what those implementations do. As an example, GFileIcon would be a one-liner: https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gio/gfileicon.c#n258 . Whether this is worth your time and a good enough solution for you is difficult to say...

Comment: I'll try that first. Will get to you later. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I finally decided to update the whole GLib stuff to a version higher than 2.38 (2.45.2 according to Github's rep).

Compilation works fine, until I get to the linking, where I get "undefined reference" errors. The -l gcc options reference libgio-2.0 which is normally found in GTK+ /bin directory, but I suspect that this library was compiled from an older version of GLib (2.34 if I'm not mistaken).

I'll maybe try to build the GLib master branch first, if that is the correct way to go.

Comment: Just remember you get to keep both pieces if it doesn't work: I don't know if Windows compatibility gets any testing apart from these bundle releases... GLib 2.44.1 is the latest stable release, that should be your first choice. GIO is a separate library (and in fact the one that contains GIcon), but it also builds from GLib sources.

Comment: In the end, I used another software :/

Maybe I'll try again some other time.

Thanks anyway.